# How to print custom size page using Fastreport 4.0 / delphi xe 2?

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I have FastReport page A3 size landscape orientation.
   How can I print in /split it / on A4 with landscape orientation.

When I use:

```
 PrintMode = pmSplit,
 PrintOnSheet = 9 ,
 page.Orientation := poLandscape;
```

The Printed pages are with Portrait orientation, but I need Landscape .
 How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FR split pages automatically, you can't to change this behavior without FR's sources changing (procedure SplitPage in the frxPreviewPages.pas)